# Convert output from FactorInteger to LaTeX

Tags: string-manipulation, latex

Is it possible to transform the output from `FactorInteger` to form a LaTeX-output as follows; e.g.

```
FactorInteger[4708352000]
```

becomes, in text form,

```
2^{14} \cdot 5^3 \cdot 11^2 \cdot 19
```

TIA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create the right structure and then use [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm):

```
CenterDot @@ Replace[
    FactorInteger[4708352000],
    {b_, p_Integer} :> HoldForm[b]^p,
    {1}
] // TeXForm
```

> 2^{14}\cdot 5^3\cdot 11^2\cdot 19

Comment: Thanks. Can this be made into a function for shorter typing?